# Law enforcement cracked my phone?

Tags: cryptography, android, brute-force, password-cracking

Police took my android phone a few months ago. It was encrypted and had the 10 max tries destruction thing set on.

I noticed that yesterday the device disappeared from my android device manager. Until then it hadn't been online since it was taken. Does that mean they got in it or just wiped it?

The phone was switched off when it was taken. Can they brute force the pass offline as many times as they want?

Comment: How good was your pin? Or were you using a pattern? It is hard to tell what you are even asking. There is no way we can know what the police have tried and whether or not they were successful.

Comment: @mikeazo - I think he is not asking about safty of his pass/pin. He is asking about breaking the max tries.

Comment: @Vilican but if the PIN is crap, the max tries does not matter.

Comment: @mikeazo - Lets assume it is not crap. If he knew that it is a crap, he would not ask here.

Comment: @Robert, https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114890/how-can-my-lost-phone-disappear-from-my-android-device-manager-device-list

Comment: @Robert - Yes, you can copy it. In the worst scenario you just get the hardware memory from the device and connect it.

Answer (score 3):

One option: They can clone the whole system to a computer or another phone. After that, they will do the tries. After it wipes itself, they will clone it again.

Second option: If it is the data what is going on, they can copy it to a PC and crack it there. No wiping applies on that in this case ...

Comment: He said the device was encrypted though, so copying to a PC to crack it there wouldn't work; assuming a modern up-to-date encryption algorithm was used (which I'm sure it was since it was the M8).

Comment: Also, can you cite a reference, or a link that can prove what you're talking about for your comment where you said:   "No wiping applies on that in this case..." I don't see how copying the data will do you any good anyway, as you're still trying to crack the PIN.  I'm sure the police want the data on the device, but plugging it into the computer and trying to crack it doesn't magically somehow turn the 10 max tries off.  If you can show me somewhere stating that it does from a credible source I'll gladly retract my statement and change my vote.

Comment: @BradBouchard - No, I mean if you encrypt a device that has a system that wipes it after 10 tries what about just copying the documents to a PC? You have just the encrypted data. You get algorithm from the system and decipher it elsewhere without the max-tries.

Comment: I replied to the original post. I'm curious if they can brute force it thousands of times per second if they wanted to.

Comment: You still haven't provided evidence to back up your claims Vilican.  And, @Robert, I'd put something on the Android Stack Exchange to see if they know of the offline bruting capabilities.

Comment: @BradBouchard to bypass the 10 tries you could  directly access the flash memory on the chips. https://source.android.com/security this page says it's a kernel module that handles decryption.